# How to prove via induction recursive sequence

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, proof-writing

$a_1:=1$

$a_{n+1}(a_n+1):=a_n$

> To show: For all $n\in\mathbb{N}_1$ the following holds
>   $$a_n=\frac{1}{n}$$

n=1 is trivial

Assumption: For some n=k
$$a_k=\frac{1}{k}$$ holds.

Claim: For n=k+1
$$a_{k+1}=\frac{1}{k+1}$$ holds then too.
$$a_{k+1}(a_k+1)=a_k$$
we insert our assumtion (replace $a_k$ with the fraction)
$$a_{k+1}(\frac{1}{k}+1)=\frac{1}{k}$$
$$a_{k+1}=\frac{1}{k(\frac{1}{k}+1)}=\frac{1}{k+1}$$

I got the following question: is it necessary for recursive sequences to prove n=1 and n=2 or is n=1 sufficient?

Also: Is the proof ok, or am I absolutly forced to manipulate $a_k=\frac{1}{k}$ into the claim?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The case $n=1$ is *sufficient*.

Your proof is fine.